# Automatic splash page for domain with correct nameservers?

Tags: cpanel

I've got a cpanel website with domain name "mysite.com". I intend to offer a service whereby a domain name is registered for each new user. However, when the domain name is registered, it will have the "default nameservers". I want to set up these default nameservers, so that if you view any domain name with these nameservers, that it will automatically show my splash page.

As far as I know, this would normally require zone entries on the server to which the nameservers are pointing. Is that correct or is there some kind of wildcard method one can use to do this in an easy way? Or am I correct in assuming I would probably need to call the cPanel API to create zone entries somehow?